# child_process.spawn never fires a "close" Event

Tags: javascript, child-process, spawn

Im am using child_process.spawn to restore a mongodb from a script. I am triggering this process twice in parallel with a promise. While the first returns successfully, the second just keeps stuck at producing output via stderr, this code here never fires:

```
    spawnprocess.on('close', (code) => {
        if (code === 0) {
            console.log(`Log Test Database Setup: ${collection} successfully restored`);
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject('There was an error');
        }
    });
```

This is what is returned until I press CTRL + C:

```
Progress:  2019-06-27T21:19:43.962+0200 [########################]  DB.collection2 1.39MB/1.39MB  (100.0%)
Progress:  2019-06-27T21:19:46.962+0200 [########################]  DB.collection2  1.39MB/1.39MB  (100.0%)
Progress:  2019-06-27T21:19:49.962+0200 [########################]  DB.collection2  1.39MB/1.39MB  (100.0%)
```

**Function to trigger restore**

```
const restoreDB = function(drop, collection) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(`Log Test Database Setup: ${collection} restore started`);
        let spawnArguments = [
            `./dump/db/${collection}.bson`,
            '--host', 'localhost',
            '--port', portDev,
            '--db', dbNameDev
        ];

        if (drop) {
            spawnArguments.push('--drop');
        }

        const spawnprocess = spawn(mongorestorePath, spawnArguments,
            {shell: true}
        );

        spawnprocess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log('Progress: ', data.toString('ascii'));
        });

        spawnprocess.on('close', (code) => {
            if (code === 0) {
                console.log(`Log Test Database Setup: ${collection} successfully restored`);
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject('There was an error');
            }
        });
    });   
};
```

Comment: How do you "trigger twice in parallel"?

Comment: Maybe the terminology is wrong, but I am doing:     await Promise.all([
        restoreDB(true, 'collection1'),
        restoreDB(true, 'collection2')
    ]);

The code above is part of the restoreDB function.

Comment: I was thinking about "spawnprocess" - is it local to restoreDB?

Comment: Yes. i edited this in above

Comment: Have you tried to run sequentially?

Comment: That seems to run. Any suggestion what the problem might be?

Comment: I thought it might not be a good idea to restore to the same database in parallel. Could be a bug in mongod as well. What version are you using? Can you update?

Comment: Maybe it would help to make use of the "collection" argument...

Comment: I am passing the collection argument, which is just the name of the collection. Although running everything squentially, I am getting the 100% error again now...So weird